# Permission to backup db on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What specific permissions are required to backup databases on SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BACKUP DATABASE and BACKUP LOG permissions default to members of the sysadmin fixed server role and the db_owner and db_backupoperator fixed database roles. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx#100bfeff-8b07-4c06-8793-70b995f8fcff is a more specific link.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx#100bfeff-8b07-4c06-8793-70b995f8fcff